# After installing pandas it only gets recognized by python not python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My system has python 2.7 in `usr/bin/python` and python 3 in `usr/bin/python3`.

I need to use pandas and it seems it was not installed. (I got the No module named pandas)

so I did `pip install pandas` and it got installed.

My problem is that if I type `python` I can import pandas without problem but if I type `python3` and I am in the python 3 environment, I cannot import pandas and I get a "No module named pandas"

How can I install pandas to be found by python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`which pip` will probably tell you that pip by itself is the python2 installer. To explicitly install into python3 do

`pip3 install pandas`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pip -V
pip3 -V
```

I'm go to believe the first returns something like:

```
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

The second should return something like:

```
pip 20.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

If the second returns something then:

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Otherwise you will need to use the package manager to install it.